# Newton's Third law quiz problem. Which answer is correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

On my recent physics quiz I encountered this question: ”Two hockey players push each other with a force of 120 N. Player 1 is on the left and has a mass of 85 kg and experiences a frictional force of 12 N. Player 2 is on the right and has a mass of 135 kg and experiences a friction of 15 N. Find the acceleration of player 1.” The way I understood the question was that player 2 exerted a Force of 120 N[Left] on player 1 and player 1 pushed player 2 back with a force of 120 N[Right] as the reaction force therefore the applied force on player 1 would be 120 N[Left] and the resulting net force with the subtraction of friction would be 108 N[Left] and therefore using Newton’s second law the acceleration on player 1 would be about 1.3 m/s^2[left]
Here is a free body diagram:

[image]

But my teacher explains something more like this:

[image]

So that there are two applied forces equal in magnitude and in the opposite direction each with their on separate third law force pair meaning that the net force on player one would be more like 228N[Left] and therefore the acceleration about 2.7 m/s^2[Left]. So which is the correct answer?

Comment: I think your teacher is right. They both push each other with a force of 120 N. Your free body diagram was right if only the player on the right pushed

Comment: But even in the first diagram both players are pushing each other as player one pushes player two with a force of 120 N also player two pushes player one with the same amount of force as a reaction so technically both players are being pushed.

Comment: @soroushmirghasemi Not true. In the first diagram, only the player on the right is applying a force. The only force coming from the left is the reaction force from Newton's 3rd law. They're not applying a force in their own right (as they should be from the question). They each apply a force, so each require their own applied, reaction pairs. You've only included the applied, reaction pair for player 2.

Comment: The question appears ambiguous. Do they push on each others bodies, in which case you need a reaction force to both pushes, or do they push on each others hands, in which case the push by one is the reaction of the other.